# Loop the Items in the Repeater for Timeline display

Tags: jquery, foreach, repeater, gsap

I am using Timeline to animate(Tweening) my Repeater items. There are multiple items in the Repeater. I would like to display first three items in my Timeline and then next three items until the end of all items.

Repeat this process once I am done with the items in the Repeater. My logic displays all the items and repeats once it reaches the end but I would like to do it for the set of three.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready() {
        CSSPlugin.defaultTransformPerspective = 600;
        var t1 = new TimelineMax({ repeat: 1000, yoyo: true, repeatDelay: .5 });

            $('.tick').each(function (index, item) {

                if (index == 0) {
                    t1.to(item, .3, { x: 20, ease: Back.easeOut });
                    t1.to(item, 0.4, { x: 0, ease:Back.easeOut, opacity:50 })
                }
                else {

                    t1.from(item, 0.7, { x: 100, rotationX: -90, transformOrigin: "50% 0px", ease: Back.easeOut })
                }
            });
    });
   </script>
```

Can someone suggest me what would be better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into the TimelineMax callbacks in the special properties:

http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/TimelineMax.html

if you use the **onRepeat** callback.. a function can get called on every repeat

> **onRepeat** : Function - A function that should be called each time the timeline repeats
>
> **onRepeatParams** : Array - An Array of parameters to pass the onRepeat function. For example, *new TimelineMax({repeat:3, onRepeat:myFunction, onRepeatParams:[mc, "param2"]});* To self-reference the timeline instance itself in one of the parameters, use "{self}", like: onRepeatParams:["{self}", "param2"]
>
> **onRepeatScope** : Object - Defines the scope of the onRepeat function (what "this" refers to inside that function).

```
var t1 = new TimelineMax({
        repeat: 1000, 
        yoyo: true, 
        repeatDelay: .5, 
        onRepeat: myFunction, // use function or anonymous function(){}
        onRepeatParams: [mc, "param2"] // pass parameters to onRepeat callback
});
```